# Setting Dynamic Range for multiple sheets in a workbook, excluding 2 sheets. (error 438) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error message 438, while executing this code.

I have 16 worksheets in my workbook out of which I need to run this dynamic range code for 14 worksheets.

1. To find the range starting from cell A2 in each sheet (except 2 sheets).
2. And clear the contents of this selected range.
   *(i dont want to use .usedrange function)
   the Objective of the Code is:

`Sub DynamicRange()

```
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim twb As ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim getLastCell As Range
Dim shtrng As Range

'Answer = MsgBox("The file may contain data, which will be lost if you proceed" & vbCrLf & "Save the
'file with a different file name to retain data" & vbCrLf & " Or Click Yes to proceed ", vbQuestion +
'vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Caution")
'If Answer = vbYes Then
    Set twb = Application.ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws4 In twb.Worksheets
            Set ws4 = ActiveSheet
            If ws4.Name <> "Generate Pending Log Report" And ws4.Name <> "PL1.Summary" Then
                ws4.Select
                LastRow = ws4.Cells.Find("*", ws4.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, _
                        xlPrevious).Row
                lastCol = ws4.Cells.Find("*", ws4.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, _
                        xlPrevious).Column
              Set getLastCell = ws4.Cells(LastRow, lastCol)
              Set shtrng = ActiveSheets.Range("A1", getLastCell(ws4)).Select
              'I am getting an error 438
            End If
        Next ws4

'End If
```

End Sub`

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing: `getLastCell(ws4)` when `getLastCell` is a range, not a function? Also, remove the `.Select` from the `Set shtrng = ` line

Comment: @Rory Honestly I have no clue. I copied this from a tutorial example on range. can you suggest me modification to this code?. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Set shtrng = ActiveSheets.Range("A1", getLastCell(ws4)).Select
```

to this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", getLastCell).Select
```